# how to add lightbox to image loaded externally in jquery?

Tags: jquery, lightbox

I am loading images externally using jQuery load function.. but not able add light box..

am very new to jquery.

```
var href = $('#images').attr('href');

$('#images').click(function(){
    var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';

    $('#content').hide('fast',loadContent);
    $('#load').remove();        
    $('#wrapper').append('<span id="load">LOADING...</span>');
    $('#load').fadeIn('normal');        
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr('href').substr(0,$(this).attr('href').length-3);    

    function loadContent() {
        $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent());

    }
    function showNewContent() {
        $('#content').show('normal',hideLoader());
    }
    function hideLoader() {
        $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
    }
    return false;
});
```

this function is in $(document).ready() and now i need to add function below so that images dynamically loaded become part of lightbox.

```
    $('.gallery a').lightBox({txtImage: 'Design'})
```

What am doing is... calling the file portfolio.php and taking the html inside the #content div and loading it in the #content div in the page the user is viewing.

Please help with code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that `.gallery` is a child of `#content` here.  You would add it to the `showNewContent()` function, like this:

```
function loadContent() {
    $('#content').load(toLoad,'',showNewContent);

}
function showNewContent() {
    $('#content').find('.gallery a').lightBox({txtImage: 'Design'})
                 .end().show('normal',hideLoader);
}
function hideLoader() {
    $('#load').fadeOut('normal');
}
```

Make sure to call `showNewContent` as the callback, not `showNewContent()`, (no parenthesis!), otherwise it's actually executing that function right then and trying to assign the *result* to the callback, not the function itself, and so not running it when the animation is complete.